# ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer() vs MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer()

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole, mbeans

Can anyone please clarify what the differences are between the two?

The Javadoc is really obscure for my proper understanding.

One thing I have noticed is if I use `ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()` to register my MBeans, I can view them in Jconsole.  But, not so if I use `MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer()`.

Why is that?  Is that the only diffence?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()` returns a reference to the existing MBean server within the JVM. JConsole looks at the beans on that server.

If you use `createMBeanServer()`, that will create an entirely new server. JConsole has no knowledge of it, and so will not see the beans registered with it.